# spring batch schedule define start and end interval

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am currently refactoring our current job that runs everynight from 11 PM to 4 AM on weekdays and all time on weekends. I am planning to spring batch since our current job is batch oriented.

Is it possible to schedule start and end time for jobs in spring batch?

Thanks

Comment: Why you need batch end time? do you want to terminate if the batch doesn't end on time? Currently which cron trigger you are using, for example quartz etc.

Comment: currently it is windows cron. I need end time because I cannot run these jobs on database during business hours. yes, it can be terminated as long as spring batch can resume from where it left off.

Comment: When you say end time, do you mean something like a processing window?

Comment: @MichaelMinella: yes, you can call it processing window. I have list of items to be processed within the time window. If the window is reached, I would like spring batch to resume from where it left off. I can keep a water-mark of the last item processed in database or file.

Comment: Spring Batch provides facilities to start, stop, and restart a job.  However it doesn't handle the scheduling pieces so you'd have to write the code for that yourself.

Comment: @MichaelMinella: how does having a spring scheduler call batch start and batch stop? what happens if I call batch stop when batch job is running? if records are not commited, when I call start again will it resume from where it left off?

Comment: @MichaelMinella: I posted a question on spring batch admin. kindly take a look when you get chance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731264/spring-batch-admin-ui-not-showing-jobs-that-can-be-configured

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch is not a scheduling framework. There are many good enterprise schedulers available in both the commercial and open source spaces such as Quartz, Tivoli, Control-M, etc. It is intended to work in conjunction with a scheduler, not replace a scheduler.